# Bootstrap 4 card images don't align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

So I createad a non-bootstrap class, called services.Inside it there are 3 bootstrap 4 cards with the same resolution(225x225 px).I then assign the style of it as display: flex so they are aligned horizontally.But they don't actually align.

I tried using the same width and height attributes for each of them, but it didnt work.Neither with the img style rem attribute.

```
<div class = "services">

    <div class="card">
        <img src="img/html.png" class="card-img-top" alt="HTML">
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <img src="img/css.png" class="card-img-top" alt="CSS" >         
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <img src="img/js.png" class="card-img-top" alt="JS" >
    </div>

</div>
```

The card images should have the same width and the same height being perfectly horizontally aligned.

Comment: They appear to align as expected: https://www.codeply.com/go/sbtUKXm4EA

Answer (score 0):

Hy if you are using the bootstrap you just need to add the bootstrap class

```
d-flex
```

[flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

```
<div class = "services d-flex">
          <div class="card">
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558980664-1db506751c6c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" class="card-img-top" alt="HTML">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558980664-1db506751c6c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" class="card-img-top" alt="CSS" >         
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558980664-1db506751c6c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" class="card-img-top" alt="JS" >
                </div>
          </div>
```

and the result of this code is 
[image]

If you wanna do in custom css you need to put the own style in parent class

```
display:flex;
```